# How to copy latest folder files to existing table using azure data factory

Tags: dataset, azure-data-factory, dataverse

I have a year and month and date folder, under month folder added new date folder having 4 files, every day added one date folder with 4 files, I want updated date folder files to my existing table.

Comment: can you add what you have tried and error you are facing any?

Comment: I'm trying to create pipeline, I'm getting doubt which activity I can use, please give some screenshots for my reference

Comment: @Chinnu, What pipeline do you want to create? Pipeline in ADF or in Azure DevOps?

Comment: ADF pipeline, source is ADLS and sink dataverse, load data into existing table

Comment: Please give me inputs

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest folder from the bunch of folders to transfer data you need to use the combination of dataflow activity and get metadata activity to get the latest folder.

Follow below steps to get the latest folder:

1. First using Dataflow activity create a file with all distinct folder paths in your container.
   -- First take a dataflow activity and add source file with container and use wildcards and filespaths to get file path
   [image]
   -- Then take an Aggregate transformation and group by filepath column and the crate a new column with folderpath which we will use in further.
   [image]
   `Folderpath : split(max(filepath), '/')[2]+'/'+split(max(filepath), '/')[3]+'/'+split(max(filepath), '/')[4]`
   [image]
   DataPreview:
   [image]
   -- Now store it in another container of your Storage account in CSV file.
   [image]
2. After this take a lookup to get all folder paths from the newly created file.
   [image]
3. Now create new variables to store the latest folder path as below
   [image]
4. Now pass the output of lookup to foreach to get the lastmodified data of each folder.
   [image]
5. Now under foreach take get metadata activity to get the Lastmodified date of each folder.
   [image]
6. After this get meatadata use If condition to compare the lastmodified date Using this expression `@greater(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified,variables('templastdate'))`
   [image]
7. Under this if condition take two set variables. on is to update the `templastdate` and second is to get the latest folder path as below:
   [image]
   [image]

Now in the **latestfolder** variable you will get latest folder.

[image]

Comment: I want only date folder, every day create a new date folder in the month folder, so I want only newly added date folder files into my existing table with auto mapping folder path, if tomorrow added new date folder with files, I want that files

Comment: Add this `@split(item().folderpath,'/')[2]` expression in tempfolder varibale you will get only latest date folder.